# How can I resolve the JavaScript error after upgrade magenta from M 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 in Magento 2??

Tags: magento2, frontend, knockoutjs, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

Here I upgrade Magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 so getting a javascript error can anyone help me how can I resolve this error?
[image]

Can not find out what excatly issue

Answer (score 0):

Vendor-Bundled extensions removed from magento code base from magento 2.4.4. So if you would like to use Dotmailer and Vertex extensions, you have to install them via magento marketplace:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-4.html#vendor-bundled-extensions

For Amasty payment restriction module, you should check if this module compatible with magento 2.4.5 or not.

So, trying to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and re compile DI `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and re-deploy static contents, then check if it works.